# How to access any control inside Hubsection Datatemplate in Windows 8.1 store

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, datatemplate, windows-8.1

Please tell me how to access flipview control inside **Hubsection** **DataTemplate**

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far?

Comment: Yes... recently i tried this snippet of code                    FlipView fv = GetTemplateChild("TheFipView") as FlipView;

Comment: Check this : [How do I access a control inside a XAML DataTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375375/how-do-i-access-a-control-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate)

Comment: @har07 I would like to know as well, I tried the method outlined by Jerry Nixon, but I'm stuck at the foreach loop.  For HubSection there are no items to loop through.  (i.e. no Items property)  But I don't have flipview control, just some items like map, grid etc inside the hubsection

Answer (score 12):

I don't know if you managed to solve your problem already. If you didn't here is how.

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

usage is very simple, for example in my case

```
ComboBox cb= FindChildControl<ComboBox>(HUB_HC, "SemanaHC") as ComboBox;
```

Where HUB_HC is my HubSection name and SemanaHC is a combobox inside that HubSection witch is also inside of a StackPanel. It works for me and it's simple to use

Reference: [How to access a Control inside the data template in C# Metro UI in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189715/how-to-access-a-control-inside-the-data-template-in-c-sharp-metro-ui-in-the-code)

Comment: the combo box i get using this method returns null, any idea why?

Comment: Answer code works great (minimal control tree).  Thanks!

Comment: This code snippet is excellent, thank you!

I personally modified it to have a return type of T and say `where T : DependencyObject`.

Comment: this works to find one element only, but if I am looping inside a ListView and for every ListViewItem I want to access its StackPanel which is in its DataTemplate? I tried looping but i can access only the first stackPanel of the first ListViewItem! Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deal with this is to have a user control inside the DataTemplate.
And UserControl will have the Flipview, so you can easily access the flipview there.

Comment: but isn't it the same thing? How will you access the `FlipView` in this way?

Comment: Lets say you have Page : HubPage where you have Hub control. Now in one of the sections you have this usercontrol , in that usercontrol you can access the flipview

Answer (score 1):

To access any control inside a HubSection you can do something like this:

```
var sec = MyHub.Sections[2];
var btn = sec.FindVisualChild("MyButton") as Button;
```

EDIT: in order to use FindVisualChild extension method you have to use [MyToolkit project](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/). You can download it as a Nuget Package and see the project [here](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Hope it helps!
:D

EDIT 2: The code for FindVisualChild can be found here: https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Shared/UI/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs

Comment: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection' does not contain a definition for 'FindVisualChild' and no extension method 'FindVisualChild' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I added these MyToolkit NuGet packages but FindVisualChild returns null.. Why?

Answer (score -1):

var sec = testHub.Sections[0];
var gridViewSelect = sec.FindName("Section4Header") as GridView;

FindName does the trick...

Comment: Return null in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Returns null for Windows Store App 8.1

Comment: Returns null on Windows 8.1