# Can't access elements inside the Hub in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've been trying to access some elements created inside the Hub in my app but the IDE says The name `user_Image` does not exist in the current context. `user_Image` is the element that I'm trying to access inside the hub.

How do I do this?

**XAML:**

```
<Hub x:Name="centralHub" Header="bacpac" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="658" Margin="-7,27,-55,-18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462">
            <Hub.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Panorama.png"/>
            </Hub.Background>
            <HubSection x:Name="homeSection" Header="Home">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="518" Margin="-9,-32,0,-3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="425">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Hello_Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="109" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" FontSize="60" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.894,0.523" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light">
                        <Run Text="Hello"/>

                        </TextBlock>
                        <Image x:Name="user_Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="152,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="user_Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26" Width="370"/>
```

**C# Code:**

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var profilePictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type={1}&access_token={2}", fbSession.Token.FacebookId, "square", fbSession.Token.AccessToken);
                    user_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(profilePictureUrl));
                    user_Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
                }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, UISyncContext);
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Microsoft decided that you have to define the content of `HubSection` via `DataTemplate` instead of putting it directly as `Content`. The implication is you cannot use the name of the control to access it directly.

See more here: [How to access any control inside Hubsection Datatemplate in Windows 8.1 store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126659/how-to-access-any-control-inside-hubsection-datatemplate-in-windows-8-1-store)