# Selecting elements inside UWP-Hub

Tags: c#, uwp

on my researches regarding "Selecting elements inside a Hub", I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126659/how-to-access-any-control-inside-hubsection-datatemplate-in-windows-8-1-store). The FindChildControl function works for me in most cases, but unfortunately it seems, that this function cannot address elements like Ellipses or Images.
As I'm a very beginner with C# and UWP, is there any possibility to address those elements?

For example, here's a bit of code, that should address an image inside the "weatherSec" hub-section, but it's still null.

```
        Image ResImage = FindChildControl<Image>(weatherSec, "ResultImage") as Image;
        TextBlock ResultTextBlock = FindChildControl<TextBlock>(weatherSec, "ResultTextBlock") as TextBlock;
        //var position = await LocationManager.GetPosition();

        RootObject myWeather =
            await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(
                51.43,
                6.75);

        string icon = String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Weather/{0}.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
        ResImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon, UriKind.Absolute));
        ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + "°C - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;
```

Greetings
Dada

Comment: I made a demo from your codes and the `FindChildControl` but didn't reproduce your problem, the image changed correctly. Could you please share a demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I've uploaded the complete project here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnAzwO51R3Ve71gSfFGII951rfVR
Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but unfortunately it seems, that this function cannot address elements like Ellipses or Images.

I checked your demo and reproduced the problem. The problem is you placed the `OnLoaded` inside the MainPage Constructor, in which the XAML hasn't been fully loaded. So you didn't get the Image element in `weatherSec`(actually you can't get any element there, not just the `Image` or `Eclipses`).

To fix the problem, you need to put the `Onloaded` inside `MainPage.Loaded` like below:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    InitGPIO();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;// add event
    //OnLoaded(); //comment out this line, the xaml hasn't been fully loaded
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnLoaded();
}
```