# Access control inside hub control windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have this code:

```
<HubSection x:Name="MyHub">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="MYImage" Source="{Binding image}" Height="50" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                <Button Content="Click me">
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

But I do not know how to access the text-block, I want to change the foreground color of the text-block in code behind.

Comment: You can add datatriggers to your textblock so you can trigger colour changes based on properties on your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML：

```
<Hub x:Name="myHub">
        <HubSection x:Name="myHubSection">
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textbox1" Text="text" Width="300" Height="100">
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

Code behind:

```
 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hub_section = FindVisualChildByName<HubSection>(this.myHub, "myHubSection");
        var text_box = FindVisualChildByName<WebView>(hub_section, "textbox1");
    }

    public static T FindVisualChildByName<T>(DependencyObject parent, string name)where T : DependencyObject

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            string controlName = child.GetValue(Control.NameProperty) as string;
            if (controlName == name)
            {
                return child as T;
            }
            else
            {
                T result = FindVisualChildByName<T>(child, name);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

More detailed information you could refer to [How to access a Control inside the data template in C# Metro UI in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189715/how-to-access-a-control-inside-the-data-template-in-c-sharp-metro-ui-in-the-code)