# c# - Find and modified image control by gridview selecteditem

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I need to change the source of an Image control inside a gridview datatemplate when a click event is raised in uwp. When i click on a car image, this Image needs to be modified and displayed the brand logo. I succeed with that code:

```
   <controls:AdaptiveGridView x:Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                              animations:ReorderGridAnimation.Duration="350"
                              Margin="0,12,0,0"
                              ItemHeight="200"
                              DesiredWidth="200"
                              SelectionMode="Single"
                              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                              ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"
                              >

        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MyData">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:ImageEx x:Name="ImageExControl"
                                      MaxHeight="200"
                                      IsCacheEnabled="True"
                                      Source="{x:Bind carsPictures}"
                                      Stretch="Fill"
                                      PlaceholderSource="/Assets/placeholder_cover.jpg"
                                      PlaceholderStretch="Uniform"/>
                        </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

Thanks to that post : [How to access a Control inside the data template in C# Metro UI in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189715/how-to-access-a-control-inside-the-data-template-in-c-sharp-metro-ui-in-the-code), 
i can use FindChildControl(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName) method.

In code behind:

```
 private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var newData = (MyData)e.ClickedItem;

        ImageEx ex = FindChildControl<ImageEx>(this, "ImageExControl") as ImageEx;
        ex.Source = newData.brandLogo;
    }
```

The problem is this gridview contains 30 cars picture and only the first Image control is modified when a click event is raised. I don't know how to use the AdaptiveGridView.SelectedItem to change the clicked Image control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Get `GridViewItem` that has been `Clicked` so that you can change the image of the Clicked Item. Change your `ItemClick` Event to something like below.

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewItem item = myGridView.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    MyData newData = (MyData)e.ClickedItem;
    ImageEx ex = FindChildControl<ImageEx>(item, "ImageExControl") as ImageEx;
    ex.Source = newData.brandLogo;
}
```

Hope This Helps.